# Consecutive MPI non-blocking calls

Tags: c++, mpi, distributed-computing, hpc, openmpi

I have been wondering how MPI runtime would differentiate messages between multiple non-blocking calls (inside a same comm world)?

ex: Say we have multiple `Iallgather` operations.

```cpp
...
auto res1 = MPI_Iallgather(... , MPI_COMM_WORLD, req[0]);
auto res2 = MPI_Iallgather(... , MPI_COMM_WORLD, req[1]);
MPI_Waitall(2, req, MPI_STATUSES_IGNORE);
...
```

In `Isend/Irecv` routines, there's a `int tag` parameter. But for other non-blocking calls, there's no tag param.
When we create a `MPI_Request` object, would it create a unique tag?

Answer (score 1):

Since, as you observe, there is no tag, there may be a problem if two processes issue the `Iallgather`s in different orders. Therefore all processes need to issue the non-blocking collectives in the same order. The request object offers no help here, because the first request corresponds to whatever you do first, on whatver process, so you can have mismatches there.